# how to convert swift::string to char * in cpp

Tags: c++, swift, string

I have a need to interoperate between cpp and swift. Here when we return a 'String' type from swift to cpp, the type that we receive in cpp is 'swift::string'.

I wanted to convert 'swift::string' to char* in cpp. Any Idea on how can this be achieved?

Comment: Seems to be possible simply to [cast to `std::string`](https://www.swift.org/documentation/cxx-interop/#using-swift-string-in-c). Maybe some of the mentioned, but not listed member functions even give direct access to the underlying representation?